# Можно ли упростить такой запрос в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у меня вот такой запрос:

```
$query="SELECT *,
(SELECT  CONCAT(?, '/sadm/clients/', `users`.`UID`, '.html')) AS 'Edit',
(SELECT `Login`  FROM `t_sysuser` WHERE `t_sysuser`.`UID`=`managerId`) as `managerId`,
(SELECT `City`  FROM `t_sysuser` WHERE `t_sysuser`.`UID`=`managerId`) as `CityId` 
FROM `users` 
ORDER BY `UID` 
DESC 
LIMIT ?d, ?d;";
```

В нем фактически две одинаковые строки:

```
(SELECT `Login`  FROM `t_sysuser` WHERE `t_sysuser`.`UID`=`managerId`) as `managerId`,
(SELECT `City`  FROM `t_sysuser` WHERE `t_sysuser`.`UID`=`managerId`) as `CityId`
```

Можно это упростить как-то?
Мне нужны не только колонки `Login` и `City`, но и ещё три из `t_sysuser`.
Может есть какой-то хитрый синтаксис?

Или как-то получить массивом все поля колонки.

Answer (score 2):

Типа так?

```
SELECT *,
       CONCAT(?, '/sadm/clients/', `users`.`UID`, '.html') AS 'Edit',
       `t_sysuser`.`Login` as `managerId`,
       `t_sysuser`.`City`  as `CityId` 
FROM `users`, `t_sysuser` 
WHERE `t_sysuser`.`UID`=`users`.`managerId`
ORDER BY `users`.`UID` DESC 
LIMIT ?d, ?d;
```